# mysqli_qeury does't work correctly. i need help^

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have problems with my mysqli_query, it wil not insert into the database but in phpmyadmin in sql it works but in website not.
here my code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Gelieve uw e mail in te voeren.">
    <input type="submit" name"submit" value="Subscribe"> 
</form>


<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('**', '**', '**', '**');
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
       mysqli_query($db, "insert into `t_nieuwsbrief` VALUES ('', '$email')"); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: (1) Always list the columns when using `INSERT`.  (2) Always use parameters when passing values into a query.  Those two things will probably fix your problem.

Comment: does it shows an error message ?

Comment: @OmisBrown no i don't get any error msg.

Comment: You don't get one because you don't look for one. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @GordonLinoff you mean this? mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `t_nieuwsbrief` (`d_id`, `d_email`) VALUES ('', '$email')");

Comment: Closer, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php, `$stmt = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO t_nieuwsbrief (d_id, d_email) VALUES ('', ?)");` then bind the email and execute. Also you don't need the `d_id` and `''`, assuming that is auto incrementing. Having your table definition and the result of the error reporting would help.

Comment: Since you are just inserting a blank value you can also get rid of the id column and first value. `(d_email) VALUES (?)`

Comment: @Sarkis Well I think you need to specify which are the columns that you want to insert between () neat to the table name !

Comment: @OmisBrown the email fild is getting by $email = $_POST['email'] and in VALUES is listed as '$email' .

Comment: I meant you have to write the query like this mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO t_nieuwsbrief (name_column_id, name_column_email) VALUES ('', '$email')")

Comment: @OmisBrown  mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO t_nieuwsbrief (d_id, d_email) VALUES ('', '$email')");  yes i have like that but also same thing does't work.

Answer (score 0):

use your mysql query with correct syntax

Try this

```
mysqli_query($db, 'INSERT INTO t_nieuwsbrief(email) VALUES ("'.$email.'")');
```